# Voting eligibility requirements on election pages

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

Who is eligible to vote in a community moderator election? I see answers saying that [any community member with at least 150 reputation may vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135335/how-to-vote-for-a-nominee-in-moderator-elections) and [a question asking the reason for that number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135778/why-is-150-reputation-needed-to-vote-in-elections), but I had trouble finding a reference to the 150 reputation requirement.
It turns out it appears in a right sidebar on https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election but not in the main text on https://stackoverflow.com/election/5. Without the query string, the sidebar text is different.

I did find the requirement in [this SQL query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60932/users-eligible-for-voting-in-the-2012-stack-overflow-moderator-elections) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/).

Does the sidebar text mention the 150 reputation requirement only during elections? Shouldn't it listed on https://stackoverflow.com/election/6 or https://stackoverflow.com/election/5 all the time?

Comment: If you are eligible to vote, you receive a notification during the elections (similar to the badge and reputation notifications)

Answer (score 3):

If you *can* vote, you get a notification when the primary and final election stages begin.

If you *can't* vote, the page tells you this when you visit it.

Voting only happens in the primary and election stages, which is why those two pages have this information documented in the sidebar; for the nomination stage (the first page), the only possible action is to nominate yourself, so the reputation requirements for *that* are noted in the sidebar instead.

I think this is reasonably well documented already, but if you have specific suggestions for improvement don't hesitate to toss 'em out.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: If you gain the qualifications for participation while the proceedings have already started, will you immediately get that notification, or did you miss the personal invite for good?

Comment: Haven't tested that, but IIRC the notifications are triggered when each phase of the election begins - if you aren't eligible at that time, you don't get 'em. You do still get a link in the bulletin on pretty near every page of the site though.